# Cant get my forms data into database. Getting error: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'firstname' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, swing, user-interface

This is my action event on button click: I want this button to call a function that has the code to insert values into database. I know if I get all the code right here it will work fine. I have already coded that way. But I want to do it by just calling the function in GUI section and then calling functions.

```
JButton btnregister = new JButton("Register");
btnregister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DBQueries admin = new DBQueries();
        admin.addAdmin();
    }
});
```

And this here is my function that is being called:

```
public void addAdmin() {
    Register registration = new Register();

    String firstname = registration.getTxtfirstName();
    String lastname = registration.getTxtlastName();
    String email = registration.getTxtemail();
    String mobile = registration.getTxtmobile();
    String username = registration.getTxtusername();
    String password = registration.getTxtpassword();
    
    String addAdmin = "INSERT into admin (adminid, firstname, lastname, email, mobile, username, password)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement(addAdmin);
        pst.setInt(1, 45);
        pst.setString(2, firstname);
        pst.setString(3, lastname);
        pst.setString(4, email);
        pst.setString(5, mobile);
        pst.setString(6, username);
        pst.setString(7, password);
        int updatedRowCount = pst.executeUpdate();
        
        if(updatedRowCount > 0) {
            System.out.println("Admin added successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to add Admin");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should think that the `firstname` field in the `admin` table doesn't allow for enough characters you are trying to insert into the field. Check DB table creation. What is the CREATE TABLE sql string?

Comment: my DB table has 7 columns namely:
"adminid, firstname, lastname, email, mobile, username and password." in the given order

adminid is int with default length and other columns has type as varchar with 50 their length which i think is enough to hold the inputs i give.

also i tried with single character input on everyfield, but the error is still the same even when i give single character input.